# Link function is not triggered from Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, jasmine

I am trying to test simple directive that changes the format of date and act as a filter for input type:

```
module.exports = function () {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
            ngModelController.$formatters.push(function(data) {
                if(data != null){
                    return  data.getHours() + ":" + data.getMinutes();
                }
            });
        }
    };
 };
```

However link function is not triggered from jasmine test:

```
describe('formatTimeDirective', function () {

    var scope, element, compile, html;

    beforeEach(function(){
        html = '<input type="text" format-time ng-model="duration" id="duration"/>';

        inject(function($compile, $rootScope){
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            scope.duration = new Date(new Date().setHours(0,0,0,0));
            element = angular.element(html);
            compile = $compile(element);
            compile(scope);
            scope.$digest();
        })
    });


    it('should format input value to hh:mm', function(){
        element.trigger('input');
        scope.$digest();
        expect(element.val()).toEqual('00:00');
    });

});
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Your directive definition does not seem to include the name of the directive (which i guess should be 'formatTime')?

Comment: I am using Browserify. The definition of directive is in index.js file. The error I am getting is that expected value is not correct. Value is date instead of formatted date. And linked function is never called.

Comment: Does it not say what value is returned? getHours() returns an integer so your directive might just simply return '0:00' and not '00:00'

Comment: It returns string in date format. The problem is that linked function is never triggered. I tried to consol.log in the link function, but don´t see any output.